# Spark History Logs Are Not Enabled with Oozie Spark Action in Cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, oozie

I am trying to follow this instructions to enable history logs with Spark Oozie action.
https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

To ensure that your Spark job shows up in the Spark History Server, make sure to specify these three Spark configuration properties either in spark-opts with --conf or from oozie.service.SparkConfigurationService.spark.configurations

1. spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://SPH-HOST:18088
2. spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://NN:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
3. spark.eventLog.enabled=true

Workflow defintion looks like this:

```
<action name="spark-9e7c">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>yarn-cluster</master>
        <mode>cluster</mode>
        <name>Correlation Engine</name>
          <class>Main Class</class>
        <jar>hdfs://<MACHINE IP>:8020/USER JAR</jar>
          <spark-opts> --conf spark.eventLog.dir=<MACHINE IP>:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.address=<MACHINE IP>:18088/</spark-opts>
    </spark>
    <ok to="email-f5d5"/>
    <error to="email-a687"/>
</action>
```

When I test from a shell script history logs are logged correctly but with Oozie actions logs are not logged correctly.  I have set all the three propeties.

Comment: Hi Please check my answer instead of spark-opts try to pass argument like mentioned in my answer

Comment: If you are okay with the answer, please flag-up "accepted-by-owner" Thx

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response RamPrasad. I moved the properties as recommended by you in the configuration section.  Now I can some logs in the /user/spark/applictionHistory location as .inprogress.  But still cannot see any log in the history server.

Comment: it should work. pls check again. pls check any further mistakes

Comment: For me adding properties to both spark-opts and configuration worked.  Thanks so much RamPrasad for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my experience, I think you have passed arguments in wrong place.

Please refer to below xml snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.4' name='sparkjob'>
    <start to='spark-process' />
    <action name='spark-process'>
        <spark xmlns='uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1'>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.service.SparkConfigurationService.spark.configurations</name>
                <value>spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://node1.analytics.sub:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory,spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://node1.analytics.sub:18088,spark.eventLog.enabled=true</value>
            </property>
            <!--property>
                <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                <value>/user/ambari-qa/sparkActionPython/hive-config.xml</value>
            </property-->
            <!--property>
                <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property-->
            <property>
                <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
                <value>/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150831190253/spark</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <master>yarn-client</master>
        <!--master>local[4]</master-->
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>wordcount</name>
        <jar>/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/wordcount.py</jar>
        <spark-opts>--executor-memory 1G --driver-memory 1G --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 2 --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2557-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar</spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to='end'/>
        <error to='spark-fail'/>
    </action>
    <kill name='spark-fail'>
        <message>Spark job failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```